# Setting a WebView to Auto Height in Windows Store Apps / Metro XAML

Tags: xaml, webview, windows-8, windows-runtime

If I put a `TextBlock` in a `ListView` it expands the `ListView` to the length of the text. However, a `WebView` does not do the same.

Is there anyway to get a `WebView` to stretch its parent element? Is it something which has to be done after the content has loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the `Canvas` element, the `Webview` does not stretch to accommodate its contents.  You will need to either set an absolute size on your `WebView` or find some other way to set its size that doesn't depend on its contents.

Comment: Guess I'll have to render the HTML in a TextBlock instead. Thanks